# How to add functionality to derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a base class `Circle`(simply drawing circles) and two derived, from it, classes: `Smiley` and `Frowny`, adding two distinctive features, respective *"mouth expression"* and *"eyes"*. These two classes add the new features, overriding the function `draw_lines()`<sup>1</sup> , whose original is located in `Circle`.

```
// class Smiley
class Smiley: public Circle{
public:
   Smiley(Point c, int rr)  : Circle(c,rr), r(rr) { }
   void draw_lines() const;
private:
   int r;
};

void Smiley::draw_lines() const{
    if (color().visibility())
    // add the mouth
        fl_arc(point(0).x + r/2, point(0).y + r/2, r, r, 180, 360);
    // add the eyes
        fl_arc(point(0).x + r/2, point(0).y + r/4, r/2, r/2, 0, 360);
        fl_arc(point(0).x + 3/2 * r, point(0).y + r/4, r/2, r/2, 0, 360);
    // the below is the body of the original function in Circle
    if (color().visibility())
        fl_arc(point(0).x,point(0).y,r+r,r+r,0,360);
}
// class Frowney
class Frowny: public Circle{
public:
    Frowny(Point c, int rr)  : Circle(c,rr), r(rr) { }
    void draw_lines() const;
private:
    int r;
};

void Frowny::draw_lines() const{
    if (color().visibility())
    // add the mouth
        fl_arc(point(0).x + r/2, point(0).y + r, r, r, 0, 180);
    // add the eyes
        fl_line(point(0).x + r/2 - 5, point(0).y + r/2, point(0).x + r,  point(0).y + r/4);
        fl_line(point(0).x + r + 5, point(0).y + r/4, point(0).x + 1.5*r, point(0).y + r/2);
    if (color().visibility())
        fl_arc(point(0).x,point(0).y,r+r,r+r,0,360);
}
```

Now, two new classes should be derived from class `Smiley` and `Frowny` adding specific separate feature for each of them.

```
// class SmileHat
class SmileHat: public Smiley{
public:
    SmileHat(Point c, int rr) : Smiley(c, rr), r(rr), center(c) { }
    void draw_line() const;
private:
    int r;
    Point center;
};
```

Similarly for `Frowny`, with the only difference in the shape of the hat.

### Question:

What is the standard practice for adding the new features to each of the classes `Smiley`  and `Frawney`:

1.Override the already existing(inherited) function, `draw_lines()` (again) and include the new features ?

```
void SmileHat::draw_line() const{
    if (color().visibility())
    // add triangle hat
        fl_line(center.x - r, center.y + r/2, center.x , center.y + r);
        fl_line(center.x + r, center.y + r/2, center.x, center.y + r);
    // body of the function override  in Smiley
     if (color().visibility())
    // add the mouth
        fl_arc(point(0).x + r/2, point(0).y + r/2, r, r, 180, 360);
    // add the eyes
        fl_arc(point(0).x + r/2, point(0).y + r/4, r/2, r/2, 0, 360);
        fl_arc(point(0).x + 3/2 * r, point(0).y + r/4, r/2, r/2, 0, 360);
    // the below is the body of the original function in Circle
    if (color().visibility())
        fl_arc(point(0).x,point(0).y,r+r,r+r,0,360);
}
```

2.Create a new member function to the new classes adding the new feature ?

```
void add_hat() const{
    // draw hat
}
```

3.Is there any other more efficient way of doing it ?

### Note:

I'm asking the question considering the notion of *implementation inheritance*, which I don't seem to utilize, by continuously/ repetitively overriding the same function and expanding it, i.e. in each derived class there is an explicit copy of the code from the base class with a small addition.

---

<sup>1. the function `draw_line()` is a `virtual` function in class `Circle`. That is why it is possible to override it the derived classes.</sup>

All the additional files for compilation could be found: [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/). The *FLTK* could be found [here](http://www.fltk.org/index.php).

Comment: #1 would cause some unnecessary repetition

Comment: You can override a method and call a base method inside the overridden method to avoid repetition.

Comment: inheritance would not be my choice, but you could look at [Decorator_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend a class and add new features one can:

1.Override the existing(inherited) functions(in the derived class), adding new code that represents the new features. In my case:

```
void SmileHat::draw_line() const{
    // existing old code
    Smiley::draw_line();
    // newly added feature 
    if (color().visibility())
    // add triangle hat
    fl_line(center.x - r, center.y + r/2, center.x , center.y + r);
    fl_line(center.x + r, center.y + r/2, center.x, center.y + r);
}
```

2.Define a *decorator class* containing the *basic features* to be extended and then derive different classes from it, each adding a specific extension to the basic features. In my case the class hierarchy would look like:

```
                                     class Circle
                                          |
                                          |
                      - - - -> class CircleDecorator <- - - -  
                     |            |            |             |
                     |            |            |             |    
             class withSmile class withHat1 class withHat2 class withFrown
```

Answer (score 4):

draw_lines() method should be declared as virtual:

```
virtual void Smiley::draw_lines() const {
    //draw smiley implementation here
}
```

Override draw_lines() and call base method to draw smiley:

```
virtual void SmileHat::draw_lines() const{
    Smiley::draw_lines(); //call base method to draw smiley
    //do the hat drawing here        
}
```

Comment: `virtual` belongs in the declaration of `draw_lines`, but not in the definition. (Unless they're the same, which they are not in the question.)

Comment: I do not see any virtual method in your code, but ok if you figure it out.